# Mechanised TV stand

Tags: metal, brackets, chain

I would like to create a Media Unit which has a TV that slides up and down within.

I don't necessarily want it to be motorised as they seem quite expensive.

I want to build it out of laminated wood and think I can make a weighted metal cog/gear/rack/drive/pulley system inside it, so I can slide the TV up and down smoothly.

The only problem is I can't find anywhere to buy these items on the internet and wonder if I've using the wrong terminology for the cogs/racks/gears/chains, etc.

Can anyone give me the correct terminology to use?

Thanks.

Comment: You are just shopping in the wrong places on the internet; terminology is fine other than a possibly regional preference for "spur gear" rather than "cog." McMaster, Enco, MSC and others all have the parts you need and are on the internet, but that makes it a shopping question, and off-topic. Cross-Atlantic shipping would be a potential problem with those suppliers for you. Not sure what there might be for online metalworking suppliers in the UK, but I'm sure that such things can be found in London, even if you have to leave the internet to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The proper name would be a TV lift.  If I were you, I'd start my design around 2 Long drawer slides mounted vertically and a counter weight or a linear actuator or screw drive for an electronic version.  These parts aren't cheap, however.

A lift kit costs less than $500 and you know it'll work.  Be sure the diy version won't cost more!